# python global variable from within class not updating by class method

Tags: python, class, global-variables, updates

I am making a chess playing AI and have a minimax algorithm that currently returns the state of the game after choosing a move: board, white_pieces and black_pieces.

My chess class handles move generation and maintenance of the state. It has some global variables:

```
__board
__white_pieces
__black_pieces
```

Which are declared within the class: body but outside of any methods. This should make it a global variable.

At the beginning of the game, these are initialized using a build_board method (not always implemented in order to test the code). I suppose it could be moved to an **init**() method at this point now that I have tested the code.

```
def build_board(self):
    for i in range(1, 17):
        self.__board[self.__white_pieces[i][1]] = i
        self.__white_pieces[i][3] = True
        self.__board[self.__black_pieces[i][1]] = -1 * i
        self.__black_pieces[i][3] = True
    for i in range(0, 20):
        self.__board[i] = 99
    for i in range(100, 120):
        self.__board[i] = 99
    for i in range(0, 8):
        self.__board[20 + 10 * i] = 99
        self.__board[20 + 10 * i + 9] = 99
```

I'm assuming this makes sense because it uses a list which is a mutable type. Sure, no problem. This edits the board.

Then, when I try to make the game take the state of the game returned by minimax and update those global variables, neither of these seem to update it:

```
def play_move(self,board,white_pieces,black_pieces):
    global __board
    global __white_pieces
    global __black_pieces
    __board = board
    __white_pieces = white_pieces
    __black_pieces = black_pieces
```

or

```
def play_move(self,board,white_pieces,black_pieces):
    self.__board = board
    self.__white_pieces = white_pieces
    self.__black_pieces = black_pieces
```

Am I misunderstanding something about how global variables work within a class? If someone could clear this up for me that would be great. Thanks!

Edit:
I can even make the playmove methods return the self.__board,self.__white_pieces,self.__black_pieces tuple and print out if they are actually the updated move and they are. Within the method, and passing those results out to another method, states that self.__xxxxx has been updated. From outside of that method though, it does not appear to update the global variables.

Comment: You say they're globals, then you access them using `self`. Are they members or globals? It looks like you're creating members with the same name as the globals, then changing them. You never modify the globals. Also, don't use globals.

Comment: I have methods that default to the current state of the board. For example:

def func(self, player, b=__board, wp=__white_pieces, bp = __black_pieces)
    ...

this is because i can't do it like this:
def func(self, player, b=self.__board, wp=self.__white_pieces, bp = self.__black_pieces)
    ....

due to the fact that default values are compiled at function definition time not runtime (when self is instantiated).

What other solution do I have to this then? Each method needs to be able to access the current state of the board and modify it.

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter rather than shift+enter - I forget that on stackoverflow enter == post

Comment: Make them default to None, then check for None in the method. You should never default to a mutable object.

Comment: And add an __init__(self): method that creates the __board, __white_pieces and __black_pieces lists? How are my methods supposed to access them?

Comment: Just make the board and piece variables members of the class, then access them with `self `.

Comment: I understand now exactly how this is bad coding - the solution I was looking for was to prefix with "classname".__xxxx. But since this is a class variable and not an instance variable, it could be mutated or set by other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared " within the class: body but outside of any methods" become class attributes, not global variables. Class attributes are shared between all instances of the class, so that's probably not what you want here.

Note that unless there's an instance attribute by the same name shadowing it, you can access a class attribute (and mutate it) from an instance, but as soon as you *set* (not mutate) this attribute on an instance, it will create an instance attribute that will shadow the class attribute:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     bar = []
...     def add(self, x):
...        self.bar.append(x)
...     def set(self, bar):
...        self.bar = bar
... 
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f1.bar
[]
>>> id(f1.bar)
140281150134752
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> f2.bar
[]
>>> id(f2.bar)
140281150134752
>>> f2.bar is f1.bar
True
>>> f1.add(42)
>>> f2.bar
[42]
>>> f1.bar
[42]
>>> f1.set([33])
>>> f1.bar
[33]
>>> f2.bar
[42]
>>> f2.bar is Foo.bar
True
>>> f1.bar is Foo.bar
False
>>>
```

Given your use case and snippet, I think that you really want your `board` etc to be instance attributes instead of globals or class attributes.

You mention that:

> Each method needs to be able to access the current state of the board and modify it.

but that's exactly the point of having instance attributes: all methods of an object share the object's state (=> attributes).

As a side note, don't prefix your attributes with a double underscore unless you **really** know what it does and **really** need it (hint: you might need this perhaps once every 10 years or so...). A single leading underscore is the convention to denote it's an implementation detail and not part of your class API.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still new to Python, coming over from Java. I kind of understood it was the equivalent of "private" keyword.